# How to use a branch as submodule?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have two branches as "current", "new". There are files in "new" that should be the same (and sync) with "current". How could I make it so instead of using `git merge current`?

--- added ---

The purpose to do this is that, "current" is maintained by team A, "new" is maintained by team B. "new" is the next generation of "current". Just separating the two versions into two branches is fine for source control. But thus, with our deployment system, either "current" or "new" could be deployed. If we found bug in "new", we need a deployment to use "current". But with these two in one branch, we could use a conf item to switch.

While having these two in one branch, `git merge` kicked in. Due to our stupid backend, I have had a lot of troubles merging.

Comment: Why not using `git merge current`? what's your point here?

Comment: Some explanation added.